# Laravel query optimazing

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-query-builder

A project has multiple task. A task is belongsTo a project

A task is belongsTo a user, and a user has many tasks

A user have an avatar

So I can get the users thats belongs to the project through the tasks

I am building a project list, and I want to display the users's avatar that belongs to a project. I'm trying the find the most optimized way to achive it. Now I am eager loading this relations, but I don't find it optimized, because it's load the task even though I don't need them, or it possible to load the users without loading the tasks?

My query looks like this:

```
return Project::with('tasks')
            ->with('tasks.user.userAvatar')
            ->with('tasks.user')
            ->orderByDesc('id')
            ->paginate(10);
```

Relations:

```
 Project class
 public function tasks()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Task::class);
    }

 Task class
 public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class,'assigned_id');
    }

 User class
 public function userAvatar()
    {
        return $this->media()->where('collection_name','user-avatar');
    }
```

Comment: To be honest, it sounds to me like you might now have your DB structured in the best way.

Do projects contain tasks that can belong to different users?

Comment: @KurtFriars yes, but if there is a way I don't want to restructure the database, its sounds like a lot of work, and to be honest I achieve my goal with mapping though the query result. But it's not optimized

Comment: If that is the case, the Project should BelongsTo the User and the Tasks should BelongsTo the Project. To get the Tasks for a User you would use a HasManyThrough.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `hasManyThrough` relationship method to grab the users via the tasks belonging to a project.

Add either one of the following methods to your Project class.

```
public function users()
{
   return $this->hasManyThrough(User::class, Task::class);
}

// OR

public function users()
{
   return $this->through('tasks')->has('user');
}
```

Then when you're grabbing the projects and user avatars:

```
return Project::with('tasks')
            ->with('users.userAvatar')
            ->with('users')
            ->orderByDesc('id')
            ->paginate(10);
```

Check out the Larvel [Has Many Through](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through) docs

Comment: Thanks for your answer! It was helpful, i didn't know about this, but in the docs:

deployments belongsTo environments what is belongsTo projects

But in my example

users hasMany tasks what belongsTo projects

So I can't implement this relation, because in the users table I don't have a foreign key to tasks table

Comment: Have you tried it?

Comment: Yes I tried, but I got an error that I don't have foregein key in users table